# Read data from MariaDB on remote server with SSH tunnel

Tags: python, ssh, mariadb, spyder, ubuntu-server

Following setup: On my local Windows machine I run Spyder with Python 3.5. Furthermore, I have a remote Ubuntu server with MariaDB on it. What I want do is loading data from the database into Spyder using an SSH tunnel and sqlalchemy.

The two solutions I'm looking at are:

(i) Use PuTTY for SSH tunnel to server as explained [here](http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html) and then in Spyder:

```
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://un_db:pw_db@127.0.0.1/db')
dbconn = engine.connect()

rslt = dbconn.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=x AND col2=y;")
df = pd.DataFrame(rslt.fetchall())
df.columns = rslt.keys()
```

This works well in terms of performance but I have opening PuTTY and building up the SSH tunnel as extra step in the process.

(ii) Use package sshtunnel, thus avoiding the PuTTY extra step:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import pandas as pd

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (hostname, 22),
    ssh_username=un_server, \
    ssh_password=pw_server,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))

server.start()

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://un_db:pw_db@127.0.0.1:' \
    + str(server.local_bind_port) + '/db')
dbconn = engine.connect()

rslt = dbconn.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=x AND col2=y;")
df = pd.DataFrame(rslt.fetchall())
df.columns = rslt.keys()
```

Building up the SSH tunnel works all fine (I think) but when I execute the query the IPython console in Spyder hangs.

Questions: Why does my use case work with PuTTY but not with package sshtunnel? And is there a difference between an SSH tunnel via PuTTY and one via package sshtunnel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched drivers from mysql.connector to [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), with the new one also solution (ii) works now:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb as mdb
import pandas as pd

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (hostname, 22),
    ssh_username=un_server, \
    ssh_password=pw_server,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))

server.start()

con = mdb.connect('127.0.0.1', un_db, pw_db, port=server.local_bind_port)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=x AND col2=y", con)

con.close()
server.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two similar solutions.

(i) In this case you create a forwarding process. (not a python process)

(ii) In this case `server.start()` start new python forwarding thread. This thread does a similar work. But it is python thread and thread will work until it is stopped. Perhaps this is the reason for your problems.

Based on the problem I can suggest three solutions.

1. You can use `sshtunnel` to create forwarding process like `PuTTY`. From README: `python -m sshtunnel -U username -P password -L :3306 -R 127.0.0.1:3306 -p 22 localhost`
2. You can just use `server.stop()` for stopping `sshtunnel` forwarding thread.
3. You also can use `with` statement syntax for automatic stopping 
   ([sshtunnel#example-2](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel#example-2))